# Viewing Report Last change date in JDE/C3ME

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jdeveloper, jde

Could someone please let me know the path to see the last change date on JDE reports (both standard and customized reports)?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could find this information inside the object librarian table (F9860). Search by object name and the last update date is near the end of the grid.

[image: Object Librarian Table]